# Git push branch error

Tags: git

The scenario is simple. From the **master** I have a branch called **myBranch**. All the time I'm working in the latter. Once I've done with some modifications I want to push my changes from my local copy of **myBranch** to the remote branch **myBranch**.
Every time I try this I get the following error/warning message

```
To git@github.com:brabbit/projectA.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:brabbit/projectA.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I proceed with a `git pull` which runs fine. Then try again with `git push` and the same error appears.

Could you explain me what does the message means and how to solve it. I am quite new to git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the default push behavior.  The branch being complained about is `master`, which doesn't appear to be the branch you are working on.  By default, Git treats `push.default` as `matching`, which means that when you say `git push`, it will push *every* branch that goes to origin.  Unfortunately, most people don't keep all their local versions of branches up-to-date, which will result in the error that you see above.

It happens because there are new commits on the `master` branch in the remote repository, but your local version of `master` doesn't have them.  When you push, Git is trying to make the remote `master` branch match your local version.  Since the local version is behind by several commits, this is a non-fast-forward update (you would *lose* history) and Git complains.

I generally recommend that folks change the `push.default` setting right away to either `upstream`, `simple`, or `current`:

```
git config push.default upstream
git config push.default simple
git config push.default current
```

You can read about the difference it the [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page (search for "push.default").  You can also see it at the command line with:

```
git help config
```

Once set, `git push` will only push the branch that you are on, and this message will go away.

Also, if you're debating on using `git push --force`, don't consider it until after you've changed your default push setting.  It's a great way to lose history, and it's also the reason why Git will change the default behavior in 2.0--though I think they should've done it already.

Answer (score 3):

You're still on the branch `myBranch`, so you need to specifically say that you only want to push that branch:

```
git push origin myBranch
```

Or, you can configure to always push the branch that you're on by default:

```
git config push.default current
```

After that, to fix the master branch:

```
git rebase origin/master master
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks, like your branch didn't configured well for `git pull`. In case you just want to push a bunch of simple commits (no merge commits) I would suggest using `git rebase`:

```
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
git push
```

In case your changes contain merge commits and you want to push it, like you see it in the history (`gitk --all`) you can do

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
git push
```